# how to insert date(not datetime) to database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert date(not datetime) to database by using:

```
<input type="date" name="latest_date">
```

, and python code as:

```
class Contacts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id'), nullable = False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    wechat = db.Column(db.String)
    note = db.Column(db.String)
    latest_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    logs = db.relationship('Con_Log', backref = 'contact')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' %self.id
```

but after submitting the form, the date column is None shows in Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latest_date = db.Column(db.DateTime) -> because its datetime not date?

Comment: Tried latet_data = db.Column(db.Date) but same, still None

Comment: whats its type in the table? is the column defined as datetime or date?

Comment: i see it's "DATE" in database. and in html it's type="date" ,format is xxxx/xx/xx

Comment: i think sql has this date format YYYY-MM-DD. but i am not sure if thats the solution :-/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).